# How do I localize the interface of Google Custom Search Control

Tags: localization, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search with a CustomSearchControl to display search results for a website. I can get the search results localized, and can add a localized no results string without problems.  However, I cannot get the search box itself to become localized, i.e. the "Search" button and "XXX results".

The Google documentation [CustomSearchControl](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#cse-el) doesn't mention any way to achieve this. Isn't this possible?

Here is the code I'm using.

```
google.load('search', '1', {language : 'is', style : google.loader.themes.MINIMALIST});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('MY_ID');

    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.setNoResultsString("Ekkert fannst.");
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');

    var queryFromUrl = parseQueryFromUrl();
    if (queryFromUrl) {
        customSearchControl.execute(queryFromUrl);
    }
}, true);
```

[image: The fields I've outlined should be localized]

Comment: Hey mate, did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, I never did manage to get this sorted :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official response from Google support

> I would like to update that currently for custom search element V2 code, you can change the search engine language only from the control panel->Basics->Language section. Whatever language you select it will be the same in all of your multilingual sites. You can't have different languages in different sites. Currently we don't have any parameter such as "language" in the Google Site Search code snippet to customize the language.
>
> In your case you can consider creating different search engine for different languages and change the Language setting in Control Panel --> Setup --> Basics --> Language in all the search engine respectively and share the query quota by adding the search engine in the Business group.
>
> Once you do that all these free search engines will share the query quota of your master GSS search engine.
>
> After that, you can configure each search engine with respective sites/URL pattern only and implement the specific search engines on respective sites.

Please review the document below to know about Language settings
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2633296?hl=en

Please review the document below know about business group:
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2633350?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

With the CSE Element v2, the search button becomes an icon, so there is no need to localize, if you switch to v2.